# Spyon provider during config phase in angular.js application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am writing unit tests for an Angular.js application (with karma and jasmine), and I want to test a certain behavior in the CONFIG phase of a module. I would like to confirm that a certain function of a PROVIDER is being called. I thought I could do this with a *spy* on the provider's method, but gaining access to the provider before the "expect" has proven rather tricky.
Here is some example code:

**Module Code (being tested)**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['restangular']);
myApp.config(['RestangularProvider', function (RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://someurl:someport/');
}]);
```

I've tried various solutions to get a reference to the RestangularProvider and apply a spy to it, and all failed. The closest I was able to get was the code below:

**Unit Test Code**

```
describe("Test if setBaseUrl was called", function () {
    var RestangularProvider;
    beforeEach(module('myApp', function(_RestangularProvider_) {
        RestangularProvider = _RestangularProvider_;
        spyOn(RestangularProvider, "setBaseUrl").and.callThrough();
    }));

    it("should call setBaseUrl.", function() {
        expect(RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

I do actually get the reference to the RestangularProvider, but the "config" function of the module gets called before that, so I think the spy doesn't get set-up.

I did find a post where the author solved a similar situation with a "work around" by testing the configured "service" instead of testing the actual call to the provider's method. In the example above, I would test the `Restangular.configuration.baseUrl` in my expect instead of testing the actual call to the provider's `setBaseUrl` method,  but this seemed like it would not be adequate in certain situations.

I am rather new to Angular.js so this may simply be a case of being totally clueless as to the whole "testing config phase", so if that's the case, please feel free to set me straight :]

Any suggestions, critiques or pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by separating out the module, whose provider I wanted to spy on, into a diferent "beforeEach" block. The altered code is below, but I still would appreciate any comments as to the whole idea of whether or not this is actually an "adequate test".

```
describe("Test if setBaseUrl was called", function () {
    var RestangularProvider;
    //Setup the spy.
    beforeEach(function () {

      module("restangular", function(_RestangularProvider_) {
        RestangularProvider = _RestangularProvider_;
        spyOn(_RestangularProvider_, 'setBaseUrl').and.callThrough();
      });
    });

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    it("should call setBaseUrl.", function() {
        expect(RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As described by OP above, you do need to get the provider before calling the module you want to test.
However, there's no need to separate it in two `beforeEach` blocks. You also must call `inject()` function (even if you have nothing to inject) at the end of the `beforeEach` block.

```
describe('Test if setBaseUrl was called', function () {
  var RestangularProvider;
  //Setup the spy.
  beforeEach(function () {

    module('restangular', function(_RestangularProvider_) {
      RestangularProvider = _RestangularProvider_;
      spyOn(_RestangularProvider_, 'setBaseUrl').and.callThrough();
    });

    module('myApp');

    inject();
  });

  it('should call setBaseUrl.', function() {
    expect(RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Source: http://java.dzone.com/articles/unit-testing-config-and-run